# Determine tilt and orientation in app

Tags: android, iphone

I am supposed to build *iPhone* and *android* app. The part of application should determine a `tilt` and `orientation` of the phone itself.

What stack of technologies should I use in order to build best experience. Is it possible to go with something similar to `Ionic` with `Angular`?

Answer (score 0):

To get the Screen orientation on a Android phone you can use :

```
int screenOrientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;

    if (screenOrientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){

          // Portrait - Do Something
    } else {

          // Landscape - Do Something
    }
```

As for the tilt on a Android phone SensorManager could help you out - 
see: [get tilt angle Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848909/get-tilt-angle-android)